# How to dynamically redirect user to a different page in Azure AD B2C based on a condition

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, ms-adal-angular

I have been trying to redirect a user to a different route based on a condition. Below is the config for auth.

```
 authConfig: {
  redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/portal',
  responseType: 'token id_token',
  strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false,
  tokenEndpoint: 'https://idmcc.b2clogin.com/idmcc.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_cc/oauth2/v2.0/token',
  loginUrl: 'https://idmcc.b2clogin.com/idmcc.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_cc/oauth2/v2.0/token',
  scope: 'openid profile https://idmcc.onmicrosoft.com/ccapi/user_impersonation',
  skipIssuerCheck: true,
  clearHashAfterLogin: true,
  oidc: true,
}
```

After a successful login, user is redirected to localhost:4200/portal but now I want user to go to a different page depending on the returning url.
E.g User tried to access a page which is protected and after login I want to go to that page. So I want to dynamically modify redirectUri.

Comment: You need to use the state parameter https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bazure-ad-b2c%5D+state

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the full question, but if you want to do something like this:

"User tried to access a page which is protected and after login I want to go to that page"

Look into guards: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate where if someone doesn't have permissions you can redirect

Comment: It already redirect to B2C login page but I want to redirect back to the url the request came from i.e the return url